# Exit DotNet Watch tool

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

How to quit/cancel the **watch tool** ?

I cannot type anymore, or run any other commands there.

Ran it in Visual Studio Terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Ctrl + C to stop the Watch tool. "Ctrl + C" works for all programs in the Windows PowerShell.